# How to display a hover or tooltips outside the flex box

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I have a component inside this class

```
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-4">
      <div  class="p-4 lg:w-1/3">
        whatever component here
      </div>

      <div  class="p-4 lg:w-1/3">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-items-start pt-2">
               <span class='tooltip rounded shadow-lg p-1 bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 -mt-8 h-auto w-auto  bg-opacity-90'>
           </span>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

The above tooltip or anything I have does not overflow to other flex boxes. I would like for the tooltip to be able to be overflow as these boxes are small.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example,

##### Component

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap m-10">
  <div  class="p-4 lg:w-1/3">
    whatever component here
  </div>

  <div  class="p-4 lg:w-1/3">
    <div class='has-tooltip'>
      <span class='tooltip rounded shadow-lg p-1 bg-gray-100 text-red-500 -mt-8'>I'm Tooltip :)</span>
      Click me!
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

##### CSS

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


.tooltip {
  @apply invisible absolute;
}

.has-tooltip:hover .tooltip {
  @apply visible z-50
}
```

Check on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lVGk7gRlK9?layout=horizontal)

Comment: Thanks for that, I also had overflow:hidden